# Can two parquet files be compared?

Tags: python, diff, parquet

I could not find an open source tool or library to compare two parquet files. Presuming I did not overlook the obvious, is there a technical reason for this?

What would a programmer need to consider before writing a parquet diff tool?

I am using Python language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest combination would be to use `pandas` together with `pyarrow`. Once you have both packages installed, you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_parquet.html to load the Apache Parquet file into a Pandas DataFrame and then use Pandas' `assert_frame_equal` on the two resulting DataFrames.

Note that this will compare the two resulting DataFrames and not the exact contents of the Parquet files. As not all Parquet types can be matched 1:1 to Pandas, information like if it was a Date or a DateTime will get lost but Pandas offers a really good comparison infrastructure.

Alternatively, you could utilise Apache Arrow (the `pyarrow` package mentioned above) and read the data into `pyarrow.Table` and check for equality. This method preserves the type information much better but is less verbose on the differences if there are some:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table1 = pq.read_table('file1.parquet')
table2 = pq.read_table('file2.parquet')

assert table1.equals(table2)
```